# Java package not found when compiling code

Tags: java, makefile, cygwin

### I am a JAVA Novice, and I am trying to run the NASA DAA-Displays project found here: [daa-display/NASA](https://github.com/nasa/daa-displays)
on my local computer. However, when I trying to run one of the makefile, I am getting an error. Prior to posting this question, I have gone through the files in the project to the best of my ability. I have followed the instructions and have the required packages to go with this project.
When I first cloned the project, I followed all the instructions that could be found in the readme.md files. However, upon following these instructions I was met with some errors. After some debugging and working my way through these errors, I have reached this point.

Here are the first errors I got when I ran the make command on the cloned folder as is (PLEASE NOTE: These errors do not exist anymore, they are just to provide reference to make sure that I have not messed up anything in the core):

```
$ make

added 86 packages, and audited 87 packages in 11s

7 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
# generate javascript files
npm run build

> daa-displays@1.0.14 build
> tsc

src/daa-displays/daa-player.ts:56:54 - error TS2792: Cannot find module '../daa-server/utils/daa-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

56 import { ExecMsg, LLAData, ScenarioDescriptor } from '../daa-server/utils/daa-types';
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/daa-displays/daa-split-view.ts:51:25 - error TS2792: Cannot find module '../daa-server/utils/daa-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

51 import { LLAData } from '../daa-server/utils/daa-types';
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/daa-displays/daa-vertical-speed-tape.ts:55:35 - error TS2792: Cannot find module '../daa-server/utils/daa-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

55 import { ResolutionElement } from '../daa-server/utils/daa-types';
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/daa-server/daa-cppProcess.ts:45:26 - error TS2792: Cannot find module './utils/fsUtils'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

45 import * as fsUtils from './utils/fsUtils';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/daa-server/daa-javaProcess.ts:46:26 - error TS2792: Cannot find module './utils/fsUtils'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

46 import * as fsUtils from './utils/fsUtils';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/daa-server/daa-server.ts:41:8 - error TS2792: Cannot find module './utils/daa-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

41 } from './utils/daa-types';
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/daa-server/daa-server.ts:42:26 - error TS2792: Cannot find module './utils/fsUtils'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

42 import * as fsUtils from './utils/fsUtils';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 7 errors in 6 files.

Errors  Files
     1  src/daa-displays/daa-player.ts:56
     1  src/daa-displays/daa-split-view.ts:51
     1  src/daa-displays/daa-vertical-speed-tape.ts:55
     1  src/daa-server/daa-cppProcess.ts:45
     1  src/daa-server/daa-javaProcess.ts:46
     2  src/daa-server/daa-server.ts:41
Files:              151
Lines:           112453
Identifiers:     148159
Symbols:         125142
Types:            49121
Instantiations:   77238
Memory used:    213710K
I/O read:         3.10s
I/O write:        0.10s
Parse time:       5.69s
Bind time:        0.91s
Check time:       6.24s
Emit time:        1.52s
Total time:      14.36s
make: *** [Makefile:19: npm] Error 2
```

---

After this, I fixed the path errors which were redirecting the code to path that do not exist.
Once this was done, I re-ran the make command, and there were 43 errors similar to the one below.

Error:
DAABandsV2.java:47: error: package gov.nasa.larcfm.ACCoRD does not exist
import gov.nasa.larcfm.ACCoRD.Alerter;

Code I am running:

```
cd utils; javac -cp ../../../daidalus-submodules/v2.0.2/Java/lib/DAIDALUS2.jar DAABandsV2.java DAAMonitorsV2.java && cp -f ../../../daidalus-submodules/v2.0.2/Java/lib/DAIDALUS2.jar ../DAIDALUSv2.0.2.jar && echo "Main-Class: DAABandsV2" > mf && jar umf mf ../DAIDALUSv2.0.2.jar DAABandsV2.class DAAMonitorsV2.class && rm -f mf
```

I tried to run the files individually in each folder, but I am not able to debug this error. I also tried to modify the path to look for the package, but it still didn't work.

It is my understanding that the package trying to be retrieved can be found at:
daa-displays/daidalus-submodules/vx.0.2/Java/src/gov/nasa/larcfm.ACCoRD
The file that is trying to retrieve this package and throwing the error is located at:
daa-displays/dist/daa-logic/Makefile

Comment: You're running `make` on a clone of the *current* git repo?

Comment: Yes.. that is what I understood was to be done based on the installation instructions found at the github readme instructions. A snippet of those:
Installation instructions
Download the latest release of DAA-Displays from the github repository.
Open a terminal window and change directory to the daa-displays folder.
Run make in the terminal window. This command will download the dependencies and create a folder dist/ with the distribution.

Do you think this is where I am going wrong?

Comment: Conceivable it's not your fault. You could post a comment there perhaps

Comment: Yes, I just did that. I appreciate you taking the time to help me work through this @g00se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

I just found out in [an issue](https://github.com/nasa/daa-displays/issues/15) of the project, that compilation is only supported on mac/linux machines (I suppose you opened it. Way to go ) but you are using Windows.

### Original Answer

If you find a project with a README.md - file, you should always read that file about any information about how to compile and run the project. The file is usually rendered on the project main page on websites like GitHub:

[image]

In your case the following sections are extremely helpful:

#### [Requirements](https://github.com/nasa/daa-displays#requirements):

> The following software is necessary to compile and execute
> DAA-Displays
>
> - NodeJS (v14.16.1 or greater) https://nodejs.org/en/download Java Open
> - JDK (1.9 or greater) https://openjdk.java.net/install
> - C++ compiler (gcc version 7.4.0 for Linux, Apple clang 11.0.0 for MacOS) Google
> - Chrome (80.0.x or greater) https://www.google.com/chrome

#### [Installation Instructions](https://github.com/nasa/daa-displays#installation-instructions):

> 1. Download the latest release of DAA-Displays from the github repository.
> 2. Open a terminal window and change directory to the daa-displays folder.
> 3. Run make in the terminal window. This command will download the dependencies and create a folder dist/ with the distribution.

Let us know if you have more questions or if this solved your problem.

Comment: I did go through the files in detail. When I first cloned the project, and followed the instructions in the README.md, I got compilation errors. With some debugging, and fixing some errors, I have reached the point where the package is not being found in the makefile that can be found within the daa-displays/dist/daa-logic folder. I know the package is located at daa-displays/daidalus-submodules path.

Comment: The Updated information is correct. I was the one who opened the issue. The maker of the project sent me a windows-compatible file that can be run directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Java compiler/machine on any Cygwin package

```
$ cygcheck -p bin/javac
Found 0 matches for bin/javac
```

So you need to look for another platform

Comment: Surely it's *possible* to install a JDK and the OP might have done that? The real point though is that there's a makefile, as alluded to by the other answer

Comment: Within cygwin, I have installed openjdk 17.0.7 as well as g++ as mentioned in the project's readme files. The reason I chose to go with Cygwin is because the rsync command was not being read when I was trying to run the master makefile on Windows Command Prompt. 
Please let me know if you have any other platform's in mind.

Comment: The makefile is designed for Linux/Unix and you might well have to install rsync too. The point is, you should be using the makefile and not home-brewing some command line compilation routine

Comment: Right, I agree. So the first step I took was run the makefile using the make command in the daa-displays folder. According to the instructions, this is all I would have needed to done in order to run the software and access it on the localhost. However, it throw 7 errors. Based on the file locations, I figured that there were some issues with the path that was specified, so I fixed that, got 43 more errors and eventually reached this point. 
I understand that running the makefile should have done the job. But it didn't, which is why I am asking for help.

Comment: Well maybe get back to the "7 errors" point and post that output *formatted as code in your **question***

Comment: @g00se I modified the question to include the initial errors I ran into. Please take a look and let me know if further information is needed. I truly do appreciate your help with this!

Comment: See comments directly under your question - this is the wrong place?

Comment: To install a JDK on Cygwin it is NOT an easy task, as it will require to bootstrap an old version of JDK and then use that version to build more recent versions. It is likely much easier to use WSL and than install `DAA-Displays` in that enviroment  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install